# tailf output as script parameter

Tags: shell-script, pipe, tail

Why is it when I leave the following tailf running:

```
tailf /var/log/z-way-server.log | grep --line-buffered device-info | gawk 'BEGIN { FS = "\"" } ; {print $4,"is",$8}'
```

I get my desired output:

```
Den Window Sensor is off
```

However, when I want this passed as a parameter to a script (which uses $1 within the script):

```
./message.sh $(tailf /var/log/z-way-server.log | grep --line-buffered device-info | gawk 'BEGIN { FS = "\"" } ; {print $4,"is",$8}')
```

It never passes the message as desired?  For clarification, `message.sh Test` would post the word "Test" to a Slack channel.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `message.sh` command is never started.  The shell first needs to evaluate the `$(...)` command in order to pass the result as arguments, but you are using `tailf` which never ends.  Compare with this:

```
ls $(echo hello;sleep 10) & sleep 1; ps
```

The `ps` will show you that `ls` has not been started, and will only get the `hello` arg when the `sleep 10` finishes and the `$()` part has finished.

Answer (score 0):

try to pass with double quotes. and if your OS supports timeout command then try with timeout (refer the below post)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430126/how-to-stop-tail-f-command-executed-in-sub-shell

if you don't want timeout, then try like this

```
#!/bin/bash

tailf /var/log/z-way-server.log | grep --line-buffered device-info | gawk 'BEGIN { FS = "\"" } ; {print $4,"is",$8}' | while read line
do
    /absolute/path/of/message.sh "${line}"
done
```

Comment: I tried with double quotes, didn't change any symptoms.  I don't think I want to do the timeout since I want this to run continuously.

Comment: updated the answer. check  now... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079626/pipe-tail-output-into-another-script

Comment: Thanks for the help but I'm getting no output at all from this.

Comment: Would it help to know that message.sh is a single 'curl' command?  I've been trying to combine commands now but having no luck.  What do you think - is that a better route to pursue?

Comment: is your command produce the output or not ?   tailf /var/log/z-way-server.log | grep --line-buffered device-info | gawk 'BEGIN { FS = "\"" } ; {print $4,"is",$8}'